# Form to delete specific attributes in Django

Tags: django, database, forms

Sorry for the noobish question, but I am trying to make a simple stock management website with Django and I could not get this part to work.
I could not get the part where I register a certain amount of crates of soda and then when it gets taken away from the stock I want the web app to register it however amount less.

My model is as follows:

```
class Drink(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    crate = models.IntegerField()
```

So if the stock manager registers 25 crates (crate) a certain drink (name) and then after some time takes 20 of the crates out for use, I want it to be able to register that 20 crates were taken out and that there are now 5 left. I want to do this on the front-end. I used this form to register a Drink object:

```
class CrateForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Drink
    fields = ["name", "category", "crate",]
    labels = {'name': "Name", "crate": "Crate",}
```

So I guess my question is: how do I create a form that allows me to subtract whatever amount of crates I want to take out for use, and then registers the remaining amount back. It’s kind of like the CRUD stuff where it lets me update that specific field crate.
PS: it should also give me an error when I try to take out 60 crates when I only have 20 crates in the stock.

Like I said I am just getting started on Django and I am stuck here for good. Any ideas??

Comment: The `CRUD` operation is often done by staff, so it can be with admin site, why do you want to handle it with frontend? What was the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

One of many ways: use an ordinary form.

```
class SoldCrateForm( forms.Form):
    quantity_sold = forms.IntegerField( ...)
```

in a `FormView`, do the work in the `form_valid` method. A secondary question is how to know which `Drink` you are operating on. You could select it in the same form, or if it's already known you could pass it in the URL. I'll assume the latter, that it's been parsed in an URL definition as `drink`:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    drink = Drink.objects.get( pk = self.kwargs['drink'] )
    stock = drink.crate
    sold = form.cleaned_data['quantity_sold']
    if sold > stock:
         form.add_error('quantity_sold',
             f'There are only {stock} crates in stock')
         return self.form_invalid( self, form)
    drink.crate =  drink.crate - sold
    drink.save()
    return super().form_valid( self, form)
```

Comment: Like I said I am a total beginner and do not have the faintest idea of what you just did. Where do I write the form and what was that about “I'll assume the latter, that it's been parsed in an URL definition as drink”? I really do not understand what you are trying to tell me. Would you mind going through it in such a way that a total beginner would understand it?

Comment: Plus I have another thing that came to mind: how would I get it to make sure that it won’t go into the negatives? I mean that once it gets to zero it should stop, it should not go on to negative 1 (-1)? I tried AutoField (like SmallAutoField).

Comment: Sorry, but I am talking Django basics. You need to work through a Django tutorial or book to better understand the Django framework, then come back. I can't explain in a few words what takes a whole tutorial.